# Why return a boolean if not being used?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've encountered multiple functions where the developer is returning a boolean, even though this boolean is not checked :

```
function  getPage()
{        
    return false;
}

<a onclick="getPage();"><img src="/myimage.gif"/>
```

This developer has since moved, why return a boolean in this case ?

Comment: Chances are the developer intended the default event behavior to be canceled when `getPage()` returns `false`, but forgot to propagate that return value from the handler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He's returning false there, because otherwise browser would follow the clicked link. By returning false, the click event is effectively "canceled". It's equivalent of preventDefault on event object.

It doesn't work in this case though, the intention probably was to do:

```
<a onclick="return getPage();"><img src="/myimage.gif"/>
```

Comment: The browser is still going to follow the link because the `onclick` event handler isn't returning anything. Though the intention is clearly to prevent the default behaviour, so +1.

Comment: true @AnthonyGrist it should be `onclick="return getPage();`

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Browser would not anyway follow anywhere, because there is no `href`.

Comment: I saw this too simply as a habit to not have a function return undefined. Perhaps this dev had this weird habit too.

Comment: Indeed, you should also add `href` as *where* to follow.